# How to search for code that contains double quotes

Tags: support, search

I'm looking for answers on SO that contain `"type": "docker"`.

How can I use/escape double quotes in the on-site search? I tried `` `"type` `` and ``` ``"type` ``` but didn't work.

So example with the above query it should match at this post: [python - Use debugger in VS Code with docker - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74082123/use-debugger-in-vs-code-with-docker/74092271#74092271)

Is it possible?

Comment: [SymbolHound is gone](https://stackapps.com/questions/2690/symbolhound-search-stack-overflow-for-special-characters#comment18724_2690).

Comment: No. On-site search is trash. Trying to get it to do what you want, unless it involves special search operators not operating on text (I.e. score, deleted, [tag], ...), is an exercise in futility. If it doesn't work with some search text, it generally can't be done. You can use SEDE or possibly a real search engine, but not on-site search.

Comment: If only real search engines could be convinced to actually listen to you and take you extremely literally if you ask nicely enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a reasonable way of limiting the number of Posts you want to search for that term, you can use SEDE.

For example with [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1687869?tag=docker&search=%22type%22%3A+%22docker%22)

```
select p.id as [Post Link] 
from posts p
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = p.id
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid and t.tagname = ##tag:string?docker##
where body like concat('%', ##search:string?"type": "docker"##, '%')
```

but don't be disappointed if the query times out. Full table scans on the Posts table take a lot of resources and a query needs to finish within 2 minutes.

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the fine [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the admirable [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).

Comment: Great, thanks! One thing I wonder, the post I mentioned [python - Use debugger in VS Code with docker - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74082123/use-debugger-in-vs-code-with-docker/74092271#74092271) is not included in the result. Does this mean it isn't indexed yet? or SEDE doesn't index all posts? You say every Sunday, but the post is a month old.

Comment: @丶Limeー来夢丶 the query only searches question at the moment.